# .raw file and how to open it? (not GIMP/PICASA)

Tags: java, image, image-processing, file-extension, picasa

EDIT: If it helps I think this application is based in html in some fashion.

I have a bunch of .raw files that are used by a java application (not mine), but I just wanted to take a look at them (atm).
I tried GIMP, PICASA, IrFanView but without success

I understand that .raw is a image or sound file (90% sure in this case is image), but can anyone open this file and let me know what you used?

http://speedy.sh/hyyh6/carpet-royal-black.raw

Thank you,

Comment: used http://www.emvlab.org/hexdump/upload/ and got my string, but no program that just give me a preview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this Online TrID File Identifier, it analizes your file and lets you know which program created it and thus could open it

http://mark0.net/onlinetrid.aspx

Comment: 100,0% ABR Adobe PhotoShop Brush then I suppose I should get adobe :S

Comment: Hope your file is not corrupted, I've tried with Picasa and at first it says "Invalid Image" but then shows a white square, not sure if it is a result of overcoming the erroneous parts.

Comment: Yes, i get the same error with many programs and many of the files. Which means that I am missing a piece of the puzzle, because the application runs and been running for many years. If you use a hexdump you get a correct string (i think). I may have to use the metadata in the image file, but I just don't think it should be that hard.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Linux user you can play with mplayer.

Comment: Sadly win7, here. I suppose I can wait a few days to get my holds on a linux machine. May not worth to put linux to just preview an image(s).

Comment: Your Linux distribution try to open your raw file with closed applications. If you want something about Linux start to learn how to use command line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks your files are camera RAW images - photos made by DSLR. These files contains raw data read directly from camera image sensor. These files are not easy to read because each DSLR model creates RAW files in a bit different way. In graphics programs like Photoshop special drivers (like Adobe Camera Raw plug-in) from DSLR manufacturer must be used. But I think Picasa should open these images. You can try Photoshop, Photoshop Elements or open-source application [RawTherapee](http://rawtherapee.com/).